# Polymer web-component inline script not loaded in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, polymer, web-component

I got a strange behavior when my polymer web-component loads in firefox.

The problem is, that the javascript after

```
<content></content>
```

is not loaded in firefox but works as expected in chrome.

I use polymer version 1.0

My element looks like this:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="my-element">

  <style>
     ...style content
  </style>

  <template>
    <svg  ...my svg></svg>

    <content></content>


    <script> --> This script is not loaded in firefox.
       ...script content
    </script>

  </template>
</dom-module>

<script>

  Polymer({
    is: 'my-element'

    ... etc ...

  });

</script>
```

Help would be greatly apreciated.

Comment: Quick check, you are using the webcomponents polyfill right?

Comment: [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but rereading the documentation I found [the solution](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html).

Before loading Polymer Script you need wait for the DOM to be ready, like this:

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
    <template>
        <svg ...></svg>

        <content></content>

     </template>
     <script>
         HTMLImports.whenReady(function () {
              Polymer({
                  is: 'my-element'
                  // (...)
              });
         });
    </script>
</dom-module>

<my-element></my-element>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a script tag inside the template you could use one of the lifecycle methods of the component like "attached" to do the same.

Comment: Yes this is what I did, I had to rewrite my code in an other way but it works now. But this doesn't explains why this issue occurs.